# Which is the first version of Android that support Multi-display?

Tags: android, display

This link [foldable-multi-display](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/foldables?#multi-display) said that

> Android 10 (API level 29) and higher supports activities on secondary displays. If an activity is running on a device with multiple displays, users can move the activity from one display to another. Multi-resume applies to multi-screen scenarios as well. Several activities can receive user input at the same time.

But on other hand, link [Android 8](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0#mds) said that

> Beginning with Android 8.0 (API level 26), the platform offers enhanced support for multiple displays. If an activity supports multi-window mode and is running on a device with multiple displays, users can move the activity from one display to another. When an app launches an activity, the app can specify which display the activity should run on.

So, i'm confusing and not sure exactly which is the first version of Android that support Multi-display ??

Comment: YES THAT'S RIGHT ANDROID 8 OREO IS THE FIRST VERSION SUPPORT MULTI DISPLAY ACTIVITY

Answer (score 1):

YES THAT'S RIGHT ANDROID 8 OREO IS THE FIRST VERSION SUPPORT MULTI DISPLAY ACTIVITY

Comment: So, what is the meaning of the sentences in the first link ?

Comment: ON 10TH VERSION ITS SUPPORT FOLDING TYPE MULTI DISPLAY FOR FOLDING TYPE PHONES  THAT'S WHAT SAY THEREON LINK